# React Native: Render on Fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently learning react & react-native. I imported a image slider on my project and includes it on my Component as this:

```
render() {
    return (
          <TopScreen style={styles.viewpager}/>
    );
  }
```

On this image slider, I fetch images from my json endpoint and populates it. It's working fine. But what I want is to understand, how can I place a 'loading' text or a spinner on this while it's loading.

I tried to check if my banners_top has already loaded on the `render()` function, but it only renders the slider when it's loaded.

On my image slider js, I currently have this:

```
var TopScreen = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount : function () {

      fetch('http://example.org/myendpoint')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          var data = responseJson.top;
          var dataSource = new ViewPager.DataSource({
            pageHasChanged: (p1, p2) => p1 !== p2,
          });

          var setIt = dataSource.cloneWithPages(data);

          this.setState({banners_top : setIt});

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      banners_top: null
    };
  },

  render: function() {

    if(!this.state.banners_top) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>lucas!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
   else {
      return (
          <ViewPager
            style={this.props.style}
            dataSource={this.state.banners_top}
            renderPage={this._renderPage}/>
      );
    } 



  },

  _renderPage: function(
    data: Object,
    pageID: number | string,) {
    return (
      <Image
        source={{uri: data.banner.image}}
        style={styles.page} />
    );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: 240,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setState will make the app re render the view.
Like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ showLoading: true});

    fetch('http://someUrl.com/api/xxx')
    .then(result.json())
    .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ showLoading: false });
        ... 
        }
    })
}
render() {
    if(this.state.showLoading === true) {
        render your header/spinner...
    }
    ...
}
```

However, you might want to look into Redux, it's a nice way to handle stuff like this a little more elegant, plus it has other nice features.
[Read about redux her](https://github.com/reactjs/redux)

Comment: Nice. But it does not render anything inside that `if`. It only renders my Slider (when it's fully loaded)

Comment: What is your initial state? To get that if (!this.state.banners_top) to be true, this.state.banner_top must be undefined/null

Comment: It's on my question: `banners_top: null`

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that. Test to check if (this.state.banner_top === null) instead. Or use an other variable to handle if it should be shown or not, it makes it clearer. Also you then can reload your images and show a spinner at that time too.

Comment: No luck here :(. It even renders the other content. Only the Slider.

Comment: If you put a logging inside if(!this.state.banners_top) { log here } nothing is printed?

Comment: Also do console.log(this.state.banners_top) in your render method before the if statements. To see wwhat value it has.

Comment: I figured it out. It's my layout. :/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okey, great! Yeah, I suspected that :)

Comment: I dont know. All views inside my navigator should contain `flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'` or do not show up. But it aligns on center, and dont on view's left-top.